# What happens to the bounty when a question gets closed?

Tags: support, closed-questions, closing, bounty

When an open bounty is on a question and this question gets closed, will I get my reputation back or can people still answer this question?

Answer (score 2):

If a question is put on hold, or it is closed, it cannot be answered any longer. It has to be re-opened first to allow answering.

If *you* put the bounty on it, you loose the reputation the moment you agree to the system to put a bounty on the question. That rep is gone, whatever happens to the question.

If you answered the question before it was put on hold / closed, then I assume OP can still award it to you, I wouldn't see any reason why not at least.

Comment: I take it from [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/27103/278314) that questions with a bounty can only be closed by a moderator, and mods also have the ability to refund the bounty if they do.

Comment: @canadianer thats an interesting link, thanks